# Subclass TextInputLayout uses broken theme

Tags: android, android-theme, material-components-android, android-textinputlayout, textinputlayout

I need to subclass `TextInputLayout` to provide a custom behaviour. However, even with an empty body, the layout picks up a different theme from somewhere. I would not be too worried if I am able to override the theme but this theme is just straight up broken, e.g. error drawable will not show.

**Vanilla layouts:**

```
            <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_username_input_layoutz"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_username_hint">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_username_input_textz"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

[image]

---

**Subclassed layout:**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.util.AttributeSet
import com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout

class CustomTextInputLayout @JvmOverloads constructor(
    context: Context,
    attrs: AttributeSet? = null,
    defStyleAttr: Int = 0
) : TextInputLayout(context, attrs, defStyleAttr) {}
```

---

```
            <somepackage.CustomTextInputLayout
                android:id="@+id/login_username_input_layoutz"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:hint="@string/login_username_hint">

                <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
                    android:id="@+id/login_username_input_textz"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

            </somepackage.CustomTextInputLayout >
```

[image]

---

Material design import: `com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0`

Parent app theme: `Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.NoActionBar`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the constructor use `defStyleAttr: Int = R.attr.textInputStyle` instead of `defStyleAttr: Int = 0`